# Como imprimir frases da menor para o maior?

Tags: java

Preciso fazer uma classe que recebe 3 frases do usuário e imprime em ordem da menor frase para a maior:

> Faça um programa para ler três frases do usuário e mostrar na tela as
>   três frases em ordem de tamanho da frase. Por exemplo: Suponha que o
>   usuário forneceu as frases seguintes:
>
> 1. Hoje eu fiquei alegre
> 2. Hoje é sexta
> 3. Ontem eu estava bem triste
>
> O resultado do programa seria:
>
> ```
> Hoje é sexta
> Hoje eu fiquei alegre
> Ontem eu estava bem triste
> ```

Já tentei de 2 formas:

1: Usando array e Collections.sort que pesquisei na net e não consegui nem entender

```
package exercicio1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 1:"));
        lista.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 2:"));
        lista.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 3:"));

        Collections.sort(lista);

        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(lista.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

2: Usando um vetor de Strings e ifs. Obs. Consegui imprimir o menor de todos porem n faço a menor ideia de como prosseguir, eu poderia facilitar esse processo usando Math.min(frase1.length(), Math.min(frase2.length(), frase3.length());

```
package exercicio1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] frases = new String[3];

        String frase1 =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 1:");
        String frase2 =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 2:");
        String frase3 =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 3:");

        if(frase1.length() < frase2.length() && frase1.length() < frase3.length()){
            frases[1] = frase1;
        }else{
            if(frase2.length() < frase1.length() && frase2.length() < frase3.length()){
                frases[1] = frase2;
            }else{
                if(frase3.length() < frase1.length() && frase3.length() < frase2.length()){
                    frases[1] = frase3;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(frases[1]);

    }
}
```

Estou o dia inteiro tentando fazer, não sei como um exercício aparentemente tão fácil está me tomando tanto tempo

Comment: A primeira forma é bem simples, so comparar as strings da lista com Comparator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeira forma que você utilizou é a mais simples, porém, o `Collections.Sort()` usado com 
 `Comparator` padrão de String só irá organizar por ordem alfabética.

Para que organize por tamanho de string, você precisa criar um `Comparator` próprio para que o método `sort()` saiba como deve organizar a lista.

A forma abaixo, retirada [desta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078670/5524514), cria `Comparator` que retorna a subtração das duas strings da vez que estão sendo comparadas:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 1:"));
        lista.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 2:"));
        lista.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Frase 3:"));

        Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return o1.length() - o2.length();
            }
        });            

        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(lista.get(i));
            System.out.println(" - tamanho: " + lista.get(i).length());

        }

    }
}
```

O funcionamento é simples: se o resultado da subtração for 0, significa que ambas as strings tem o mesmo tamanho, e neste caso, o `sort()` não irá fazer nada. Se o resultado for maior que 0, significa que a primeira string é maior que a segunda string, logo, o `sort()` irá trocá-las de posição. Se o resultado for menor que zero, quer dizer que a primeira string é menor que a segunda, neste caso o `sort()` provavelmente também não fará nada.

Para ilustrar no funcionamento do código, veja o teste abaixo. Troquei as caixas de dialogo por apenas entradas em modo de texto e recomendo que você não misture interface gráfica com texto:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add("frase que pode ser considerada muito longa");
        lista.add("frase curta");
        lista.add("frase com mais palavras");

        Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return o1.length() - o2.length();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(lista.get(i));
            System.out.println(" - tamanho: " + lista.get(i).length());

        }
    }
}
```

Veja em funcionamento no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/7F2wcs)

Comment: muito obrigado, aprendi muito com a sua ajuda